# Not able to setup cluseter in kubernets

Tags: docker, container, kubernetes

I am trying to setup a cluster using kubernetes on centos 7 VM's and stuck on the part to join worker to the cluster.

I have managed to setup the master and get the token, i added the token onto the second centos 7 system however nothing happens.

On digging the logs i am getting the below and not quite sure what exactly is causing this. I have added the host entries in the /etc/hosts file for both servers and tried resetting the master configuration twice now.

Below are the logs from the worker machine

```
Apr 22 20:11:12 ks01 kubelet: E0422 20:11:12.647230   14902 kubelet.go:2267] node "ks01" not found
Apr 22 20:11:12 ks01 kubelet: E0422 20:11:12.651006   14902 controller.go:136] failed to ensure node lease exists, will retry in 400ms, error: Unauthorized
Apr 22 20:11:12 ks01 kubelet: E0422 20:11:12.853918   14902 kubelet.go:2267] node "ks01" not found
Apr 22 20:11:12 ks01 kubelet: W0422 20:11:12.854042   14902 pod_container_deletor.go:77] Container "82896667dd899c60e767f5c25a0a3da52a2c750cc0ac280eb0a3a9b6b4f3d1d3" not found in pod's containers
Apr 22 20:11:12 ks01 kubelet: I0422 20:11:12.854076   14902 kubelet_node_status.go:294] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Apr 22 20:11:12 ks01 kubelet: E0422 20:11:12.858635   14902 csi_plugin.go:271] Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo: error updating CSINode annotation: timed out waiting for the condition; caused by: Unauthorized
Apr 22 20:11:12 ks01 kubelet: I0422 20:11:12.893113   14902 kubelet_node_status.go:70] Attempting to register node ks01
Apr 22 20:11:12 ks01 kubelet: E0422 20:11:12.895442   14902 kubelet_node_status.go:92] Unable to register node "ks01" with API server: Unauthorized
```